# android long textview cover imageview

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-layout-weight

I have some problem with long text and image on the right.
I know that problem is quite popular on the stackoverflow 
but I'm begginer and I dont know how adopt some solutions into my own project. So when text in `textview` is to long, `imageview` doent appear.
I tried use `layout_weigth` but nothing works.

[image]

On this screen you can see than only third element show the right arrow.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/data"
            android:id="@+id/image_date"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="#37a"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/gps"
            android:id="@+id/image_gps"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#37a"
            android:text="Starówka"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
            >

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/iprzod"
            android:id="@+id/image_data"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use `relative layout` instead

Answer (score 1):

change code like this and try

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#37a"
        android:text="Starówka"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Also, you can remove second linear layout(containing the only image). It's not required. Replace it with image

Comment: I need this linearlayout to keep image close to right margin, gravity doesnt't work without this linearlayout

Comment: I changed layout_width to 0 and  layout_weight to 1 and textview disappear

Answer (score 1):

First,

> android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>
> android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

doesn't work in LinearLayout's child, LinearLayout oriented like Table with single row(horizontal) or single column(vertical)

to fix this,
you have to set width to left imageView and set its layout_weight to 0, to strictly preserve its width, and move all other views inside another LinearLayout and set it to be 1

```
- LinearLayout
    - ImageView with width = 300 and weight = 0
    - LinearLayout
        - TextView with width = match_parent and weight = 1
        - another views....
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everybody for help. Your posts helped me to find the solution.  Finnaly I have added two lines
into textView and LinearLayout which contains ImageView It seems to works, and this way was the most easy to solve my problem.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/temp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-20-20"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/temp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cmj_edit"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_pen" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Add weight to your linear layout.  `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Have you tried the answer? if it solves your problem then upvote and mark as correct . https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxhef.png